# Jquery UI draggable start function code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain me this start: function code?

```
$("#car, #boat, #soccer").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        if (!done) 
            return false;
    },
});
```

Comment: done is a defined boolean, if it is done, then the user can drag `#car, #boat, #soccer`

Comment: if not done ? like not done dragging all? or not done dropping it?

Comment: @Christine, check my answer, and it shall answer all your concerns. `done` is just variable and not involved with `.draggable()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`done` is a defined variable (mostly boolean), if it equals to `true` (and not false), then the user can drag `#car`, `#boat`, and `#soccer`. This can explain it

```js
$(function(){
  
  var done = false;
  $('#tg-done').on('click', function(){
      ((done) ? done = false : done = true);
      $('p').text('`done` = ' + done);
  });
  
  $(".draggable" ).draggable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
         if(!done) return false;
      }
  });

});
```

```css
.draggable {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#333;
    border-radius:4px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button id="tg-done">Toggle `done`</button>
<p>`done` = false</p>


<div class="draggable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `start` function of `draggable` allows you to cancel the drag by returning `false`.
Here you can drag the `#car`, `#boat` and `#soccer` nodes only if the `done` var is `true`.

Comment: if (!done) means if the user is still holding the draggable?

Comment: I can't tell without the rest of the code. The `done` var should have been set previously.  
The `start` fuction is called just when the user start to drag a node, before the node begins to move. So yes the user holds the draggable but if `!done` he will immediatly release it.